# Android NumberPicker: Set min, max, default from XML

Tags: android, xml, layout, numberpicker

Is there a way to set the minimum, maximum and default values of a [NumberPicker](http://shanetully.com/2011/12/android-3-x-and-4-x-numberpicker-example/) from the XML Layout?

I'm doing it from within the Activity code:

```
np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
np.setMaxValue(120);
np.setMinValue(0);
np.setValue(30);
```

XML is obviously more appropriate , because it defines property, not behaviour.

Is there a way to set these using the XML layout?

Comment: You might need to Customize NumberPicker and then use it MyNumberPicker everywhere...and in the Constructor of MyNumberPicker get all attribute set and set values...

Comment: @MKJParekh  do you know how to set setMaxValue setMinValue for Time picker? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188983/how-to-set-the-setmaxvalue-setminvalue-for-time-picker-dailog-fragment

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is how I solved it (according to the comment of MKJParekh):

1. I created my own NumberPicker-Class

   ```
   package com.exaple.project;

   import android.annotation.TargetApi;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.widget.NumberPicker;

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)//For backward-compability
   public class MyNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

       public MyNumberPicker(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
           processAttributeSet(attrs);
       }

       public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
           processAttributeSet(attrs);
       }
       private void processAttributeSet(AttributeSet attrs) {
           //This method reads the parameters given in the xml file and sets the properties according to it
           this.setMinValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "min", 0));
           this.setMaxValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "max", 0));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now you can use this NumberPicker in your xml layout file

   ```
   <com.exaple.project.myNumberPicker
       android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       max="100"
       min="1" />
   ```

Thanks to MKJParekh for his useful comment

Comment: Works great, thanks for sharing. Pay attention when using the graphical layout editor in Eclipse: if you change anything here, the custom properties like min and max will get deleted and you have to add them manually again.

Comment: Note that it is good to define the custom XML attributes in `res/values/attrs.xml` as described in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr). This also enables IDEs / layout editors to recognize the custom attributes. The docs also say the `AttributeSet` shouldn't be used directly (as here), instead one should retrieve a `TypedArray`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.
Very surprised Google "forgot" to place these fundamental properties into the base class.

Comment: thanks a lot, you can also override setValue so you can set inside XML file.

Comment: @MazeChaZer - I think [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48219853/2957169) should just be a comment under yours. If you want to merge it into your answer, then I will delete mine.

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
<NumberPicker
  android:id="@+id/number_picker"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:minValue="@{0}"
  app:maxValue="@{120}"
  app:value="@{30}"/>
```

This works as part of Android Databinding. So, you might want to set it to true in your app level build.gradle.

```
android {
    ...

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: ERROR:activity_main.xml:27: AAPT: error: attribute minValue (aka com.example.autovolumeadjusterbyspeed:minValue) not found.

Comment: Is dataBinding enabled to true in build.gradle?

Comment: yes, it fails in build time.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an updated version that follows the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)
(and thus supports theming & Android Studio designer preview)

**values/attrs.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="NumberPickerWithXml">
        <attr name="pickerMaxValue" format="integer" />
        <attr name="pickerMinValue" format="integer" />
        <attr name="pickerDefaultValue" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**NumberPickerWithXml.kt:**

```
package com.example.library.ui

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.NumberPicker
import com.example.library.ui.R

class NumberPickerWithXml : NumberPicker {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        processXmlAttributes(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        processXmlAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        processXmlAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    }

    private fun processXmlAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0) {
        val attributes = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

        try {
            this.minValue = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml_pickerMinValue, 0)
            this.maxValue = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml_pickerMaxValue, 0)
            this.value = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml_pickerDefaultValue, 0)
        } finally {
            attributes.recycle()
        }
    }

}
```

**...or NumberPickerWithXml.java (untested):**

```
package com.example.library.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import com.example.library.ui.R;

public class NumberPickerWithXml extends NumberPicker {

    public NumberPickerWithXml(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NumberPickerWithXml(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        processXmlAttributes(attrs, 0, 0);
    }

    public NumberPickerWithXml(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        processXmlAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public NumberPickerWithXml(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        processXmlAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    private void processXmlAttributes(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        TypedArray attributes = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        try {
            this.setMinValue(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml_pickerMinValue, 0));
            this.setMaxValue(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml_pickerMaxValue, 0));
            this.setValue(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerWithXml_pickerDefaultValue, 0));
        } finally {
            attributes.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

**Usage in your layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.example.library.ui.NumberPickerWithXml
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:pickerDefaultValue="30"
        custom:pickerMaxValue="120"
        custom:pickerMinValue="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A super easy way to verify your Java code would be to throw it in a Java file in Android Studio. It would have pointed out all of the errors really fast.

Comment: @AbandonedCart - Thanks for fixing it! The Java version was a bit of an after-thought; it didn't cross my mind that I could just add a Java file to my pure Kotlin project! On reflection today, I think my answer should just be a comment under MazeChaZer's answer.

Comment: Personally, I preferred this one. It was much more complete and easier to follow, both of which may have been lost as a comment.

Comment: I'll keep it up until it becomes obsolete :)