# Android NumberPicker set min and max values in xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, numberpicker

How can we set the min and max values of a NumberPicker in XML layout file for Android 4+. I know how to do it programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android NumberPicker: Set min, max, default from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317960/android-numberpicker-set-min-max-default-from-xml)

Comment: why do we need to create our own NumberPicker. Is there no way to directly set these in Android's NumberPicker?

Comment: `why` because there is no way to set the min, max and default in the xml.

Comment: OK, so it is an incomplete widget.

Comment: that's an opinion, and there is not much point to it, but you can consider that yes, in your use case, it does not do what you need, and hence is considered *incomplete*. But you can extend it.