# Set selected values to NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have implemented a `NumberPicker` in which we can roll the numbers from 0 to 99. But my requirement is I only want `1,2,3,4,5,99`, these number to be rolled in `NumberPicker`. Is it possible to do this?

I have tried this where `mPicker` is the object of NumberPicker

```
String[] nums= {"1","2","3","4","5","99"};
mPicker.setDisplayedValues(nums);
```

But in this Am not able to roll it, only be able to type through `SoftInputKeyboard`. Can anybody help to takle this and get it done without any third party libraries.

Comment: Please have a look at here.... [Android NumberPicker: Set min, max, default from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317960/android-numberpicker-set-min-max-default-from-xml)

Comment: @user3110424 Thanks for the fast response, I solved the issue. :-)

Comment: Good happy coding :-)

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (number, picker) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by doing like this

```
mPicker.setMaxValue(5);
mPicker.setMinValue(0);

String[] nums= {"1","2","3","4","5","99"};
mPicker.setDisplayedValues(nums);
```

Setting max value to 5 and adding 5 values to to show.